# Django customized UpdateView show exception *and* return object

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a special UpdateView and ModelForm (to front my Stripe integration), and I'm wondering if there's a way to *both* return the object *and* show an error on the page in a simple way. My gut tells me no (since exceptions raise exceptions...), but any insight / input would be great.

Here's my custom modelForm's `clean` method, which is what's tied to the UpdateView.

```
def clean(self):
    if not self.user:
        raise forms.ValidationError("User needs to not be null.")
    try:
        cream = CREAM.create_or_update(self.user, self.stripeToken)
        for field in self.Meta.fields:
            self.cleaned_data[field] = getattr(cream, field)
        return self.cleaned_data
    except Exception as e:
        raise forms.ValidationError(e.message)
```

And here's the `get_object` from our old friend the UpdateView

```
def get_object(self):
    cream = CREAM.objects.filter(client=self.request.user)
    if cream.exists():
        return cream.get()
    else:
        return CREAM()
```

Thanks much!

Comment: Not really sure what you're after here. Form ValidationError exceptions are caught by the form itself and turned into error messages on the form's fields, so they don't get in the way of rendering anything you want in the view.

Comment: I want to both return a pre-existing object, *and* display the error. My current understanding is that raising the error prevents get_object from being called - is this true..?

Comment: That is - the clean() method can either return the cleaned data you can (re)render... or it can raise the exception.

Comment: No, not true at all; the `clean` method has nothing to do with what you return from get_object. As I said, the exception is caught by the form.